# flex 4 and facebook-actionscript-api : cannot login

Tags: apache-flex, facebook, flash-builder, facebook-actionscript-api

I wrote a simple application for facebook and it seems that i fail to login. 
I created a test application on facebook and i test my application by going to apps.facebook.com/

i have the following function that is being executed after ApplicationComplete event of my main application.

```
    private function initFacebook():void {
        fbApiKey = "API_KEY";
        fbSecret = "SECRET";
        fbLoaderInfo = stage.loaderInfo;
        fbSession = new FacebookSessionUtil( fbApiKey, fbSecret, fbLoaderInfo);
        fbSession.addEventListener( FacebookEvent.WAITING_FOR_LOGIN, fbWaitingForLoginHandler, false, 0, true );
        fbSession.addEventListener( FacebookEvent.CONNECT, fbConnectHandler, false, 0, true );
        fbSession.login();              

    }

    private function fbWaitingForLoginHandler( e:FacebookEvent ):void
    {
        fbSession.validateLogin();
    }

    private function fbConnectHandler( e:FacebookEvent ):void
    {
        Alert.show(fbSession.facebook.is_connected ? ' connected' : 'not connected');
    }
```

I get an alert that I'm not connected and i cannot fetch any information.
I entered the proper  api key and secret.

If it fails to do something, how can i debug and see exactly where it failed ?

thansk

Answer (score 0, accepted):

the following does work:
        private var fbook:Facebook;
        private var session:FacebookSessionUtil;
        private var fbUser:FacebookUser;

```
    private function initFacebook():void {
        session=new FacebookSessionUtil(API_KEY,SECRET,loaderInfo);
        session.addEventListener(FacebookEvent.CONNECT,onConnect);
        fbook=session.facebook;
        session.login();    

    }

    private function onConnect(e:FacebookEvent):void{
        var call:FacebookCall=fbook.post(new GetInfo([fbook.uid],[GetInfoFieldValues.ALL_VALUES]));
        call.addEventListener(FacebookEvent.COMPLETE,onGetInfo);
    }
    private function onGetInfo(e:FacebookEvent):void{
        this.fbUser=(e.data as GetInfoData).userCollection.getItemAt(0) as FacebookUser;
        <!-- fetching facebook user information from this.fbUser -->
    }
```

and i created a button that executes the following function: (only after I'm logged-in into facebook)

```
    private function onConfirmLogin():void{
        session.validateLogin();

    }
```